# memset 'CortexA8' issue under iOS5

Tags: ios5, crash-reports, memset, plcrashreporter, llvm-3.0

Since iOS5 hit the streets I have begun I have been receiving many (so many) crash reports like:

```
...
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x0
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_c.dylib  0x35ec4b3c memset$VARIANT$CortexA8 + 116
1   FooApp             0x0005ba25 -[FooViewController prepareShapes] (FooViewController.m:808)
...
```

Relevant details:

- XCode 4.2
- LLVM 3.0
- 'armv6 armv7' architectures
- iOS 5 base SDK
- targeting iOS 4.0
- crashes under iOS5 only (all iOS5 iPhone models. No iPad crashes but app isn't universal)
- Can't reproduce the crash on any of my devices (of course)

Now `[FooViewController prepareShapes]` doesn't call `memset` directly, instead passes a struct (representing a shape) to a class method that attempts to realloc it. The fact that the stack trace skips over the class method is a bit weird but no doubt it's yet more compiler magic I don't understand. Within the class method, the block that invokes `memset` is as follows:

```c
// class method invoked by [FooViewController prepareShapes]:808 (shape is coloured2DShape instance) 
shape->maxVertexCount = maxVertexes;
if (shape->maxVertexBytes != 0)
{
    free(shape->vertices);
}
shape->maxVertexBytes = sizeof(vertex_2D_4byteColour) * shape->maxVertexCount;
shape->vertices = (vertex_2D_4byteColour *)malloc(shape->maxVertexBytes);
memset(shape->vertices, 0, shape->maxVertexBytes);
```

And here's the struct being manipulated

```c
// coloured2DShape struct
typedef struct coloured2DShape
{
    vertex_2D_4byteColour* vertices;
    GLushort* indices;
    uint maxVertexBytes;
    uint maxIndexBytes;
    int vertexCount;
    int indexCount;
    int maxVertexCount;
    int maxIndexCount;
} coloured2DShape;
```

I recognise that this isn't anywhere close to the recommended way to do OpenGL, however the thing that really bamboozles me (and I am well and truly bamboozled here) is that `memset` is only blowing up under iOS5 (I'm using [QuincyKit](http://quincykit.net/) to collect crash reports and [HockeyApp](http://www.hockeyapp.net/) to aggregate them). This exact code had been cruising along under iOS4 (compiled with GCC) for months.

I hope this isn't interpreted as a 'do my homework' thing. I have spent months researching, tweaking (I've released several updates addressing this issue) and hair-pulling with no progress. I'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think that `memset` is working fine, but the call to `malloc` failed for some reason, returning `0`.

Comment: That makes sense. I've added additional checks for `malloc` failure in the latest update. If the "`memset` error" count goes down to be replaced by "`malloc` fail" errors I'll give you the answer (should know in a week or so). Any ideas why this is only popping up under iOS5?

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna publish the soution of similar crash I found after hour of debugging, maybe it would be useful for somebody...
The reason was in so stupid thing.
I had two placeholders in NSLog and only one real variable.

```
NSLog(@"lastItemDate = %@ unixtime = %@", lastItemDate);
```